# Linear interpolation of data

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a data frame with the year (x) and an associated percentage (y)

```
data.frame(x = c(1997,2000,2003,2006,2009,2010,2013,2014),
           y = c(.02,.023,.025,.024,.026,.027,.029,.031)
```

Here is a line chart of this data frame :

[image: x~y]

I would like to interpolate my data to get the percentage of missing years based on a linear regression.

I could make a linear model of each piece of curve but it would be tedious.

Is there a simple way to do it with R?

INPUT :

```
df = data.frame(
  year=c(1997,2000,2003,2006,2009,2010,2013,2014),
  percent=c(0.020, 0.023, 0.025, 0.024, 0.026, 0.027, 0.029, 0.031)
)
```

OUTPUT (for a function f) :

```
f(2006)==0.024
f(2007)==0.024.666
f(2008)==0.025.333
f(2009)==0.026
```

Comment: Why don't do a linear model on all the data instead of doing by each piece of curve ?

Comment: Because I can only assume that the percentage is linear between 2 points.

Comment: This question seems to be less related to R and more to non-linear modeling.

Comment: then why don't try a linear model of degree 2 ? `model <- lm(y~x+I(x)^2)` ?

Comment: It might be easier if you posted a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I have not had enough coffee to guess and enter data from your chart.

Comment: @OrhanYazar, you probably want to use `poly` for that.

Comment: @trosendal I disagree, I know non-linear modeling, the question is how to achieve simply this with R

Comment: @Axeman why don't use lm ?

Comment: You are kind for trying to help me but I don't want any polynomial, I want a linear regression. Bouncyball is right, I'll provide it in few minutes.

Comment: Do you want to extrapolate or interpolate? Your Q says the former, but it looks like the latter to me. Have a look at `?stats::approx`.

Comment: @DanChaltiel, lm means linear model try to use what i wrote `model <- lm(y~x+I(x)^2)`

Comment: You could try a spline fit: `spline(df$year, df$percent, n=18)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use linear *inter* polation with `zoo`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

df_complete <- complete(df, year = full_seq(year, 1))
df_complete$percent <- na.approx(df_complete$percent)


plot(df_complete)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot ! So this is interpolation and not extrapolation, I understand why I couldn't find my answer.

Comment: Yes. Interpolation is inside the range of your data, extrapolation is outside the range of your data.

Comment: seems obvious now that I know :-)